# Dynamically select LINQ SELECT fields at runtime

Tags: c#, .net, linq, frameworks, entity

I have a LINQ query to a database, with multiple linked tables, and need to return (SELECT) different fields depending on inputs.

```
ClassA has ParamA, ParamB, and ICollection<ClassB>ClassBs
ClassB has ParamD, ParamE
```

Portion of the Linq query:

```
.Select(c => new ClassA()
    {
    ParamA = c.ParamA,
    ParamB = c.ParamB,
    ClassBs = c.ClassBs.Select(p => new ClassB()
        {
        ParamD = p.ParamD,
        ParamE = p.ParamE
        }).ToList()
    }).ToList();
```

On some calls, I'll want ParamA and ParamE only.  On other calls, perhaps ParamB and ParamE.  I've been able to make this work using Expressions but not for the ICollection.  I attempted using Dynamic.Linq.Core, but couldn't find any examples for newing up in the SELECT.  I would prefer to do this with MemberExpressions...

[UPDATE]
A bit more context:  ClassA and ClassB are essentially EF Models pointing to SQL tables.  ClassA has a one-to-many relationship to ClassB, thus, why I query them in this fashion.  ClassA would be a Student record (name, address, home, etc), ClassB would be a Test record, where student may have more than one test, each test has date taken, grade, highest_score_of_class, lowest_score_of_class, and many more.

I don't always want all the fields of both tables, as there may be 1 million records, thus, why I prefer to SELECT only what is needed for the specific query and operation requested.

Comment: Sounds like a separation of concerns issue, just use an `if` *Statement* if there are not so many combinations

Comment: Each class represents a model (SQL table), bout 30 fields per table, thus there are many combinations.  Otherwise, yes, If would be easy enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may be a bit verbose, but Expressions can get that way, for example:

```
var typeClassA = typeof(ClassA);
var typeClassB = typeof(ClassB);

var parameterExpressionP = Expression.Parameter(typeClassB, "p");
var newExpression = Expression.New(typeClassB);

var paramDPropertyExpression = Expression.Property(parameterExpressionP, "ParamD");
var paramDMemberBinding = Expression.Bind(typeClassB.GetProperty("ParamD"), paramDPropertyExpression);

var paramEPropertyExpression = Expression.Property(parameterExpressionP, "ParamE");
var paramEMemberBinding = Expression.Bind(typeClassB.GetProperty("ParamE"), paramEPropertyExpression);

var memberInitExpression = Expression.MemberInit(
    newExpression,
    paramDMemberBinding, paramEMemberBinding);

var projectionExpression = Expression.Lambda<Func<ClassB, ClassB>>(memberInitExpression, parameterExpressionP);

var parameterExpressionC = Expression.Parameter(typeClassA, "c");
var selectParamExpression = Expression.Property(parameterExpressionC, "ClassBs");

var selectExpression = Expression.Call(
    typeof(Enumerable),
    nameof(Enumerable.Select),
    new[] { typeClassB, typeClassB },
    selectParamExpression, projectionExpression);

var toListExpression = Expression.Call(
    typeof(Enumerable),
    nameof(Enumerable.ToList),
    new[] { typeClassB },
    selectExpression);
```

This will create an expression something like:

```
c.ClassBs.Select(p => new ClassB() {ParamD = p.ParamD, ParamE = p.ParamE}).ToList()
```

Comment: Fantastic.  Worked perfectly!  You sir are awesome.  Well labeled, enough for me to visualize how this works.  And thank you for the quick response as well ;)